# R: calculate group statistic on data.frame that has been created from csv import - factors issue

Tags: r, dataframe, factors

I have googled and stackoverflowed this high and low but I am not finding anything that will allow me to fix the issue. So apologies in advance if this questions seems a tad basic to some.

I imported the following data from a csv (I'm just including the head):

[head of data.frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koDLV.png)

All I am simply trying to do is perform a group statistic (median) over the currency_pchg column of the data.frame, with the price_date column serving as the group using the tapply formula. However, I get a complaint as per the following screenshot.

[error message from tapply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axeL4.png)

I have tried all manner of fixes - dropping the factors from the data.frame (which doesn't work), applying `stringAsFactors = FALSE` during the csv import (again, this doesn't work - because there are some NA entries in the import file, from what I understand), and have tried using the `aggregate` function as well (an alternative to `tapply`).

However, nothing is working and I've hit a dead end here. So any guidance would be very much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Why not try `aggregate` or `dplyr` `group_by`

Comment: I don't think `stringAsFactors = FALSE` would fail because of `NA`. Please share your code and data. Use `dput(test)` and post the output here.

Comment: Please paste output as text and not as image.

Comment: Noted. I'm a noobie on here - apologies. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Column currency_pchg is most likely being read as a factor. Try converting currency_pchg to numeric in this way and then perform the aggregation:

```
#na.rm = TRUE to ignore NAs 
data %>% group_by(price_date) %>% summarise(median(as.numeric(as.character(currency_pchg)), na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thank you, sparkh2o...This works a treat. I had actually tried as.numeric(as.character(currency_pchg))) as per suggestions elsewhere and this hadn't worked. But the na.rm=TRUE argument has done the trick. Thanks again